# How to use Linq in IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, iqueryable

I want to join two entities in IQueryable

This is what I do:

```
IQueryable<EmployeeSchedule> employeeScheduleResult = 
    from empSched in ctx.EmployeeSchedules.ToList() 
    join emp in ctx.Employees.ToList() on empSched.EmployeeId equals emp.EmployeeId 
    select new {
        empSched.ScheduleId,
        empSched.ScheduleDt,
        empSched.Branch,
        empSched.StartTime,
        empSched.EndTime,
        empSched.LunchTime,
        empSched.LunchBreak,
        empSched.LunchBreak_NS,
        Employee = emp.LastName + emp.FirstName + emp.MiddleName
    };
```

And this is the error I receive:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: Side note: Get rid of the `ToList()`s.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: First, Why not get rid of join and use Include like `from empSched in ctx.EmployeeSchedules.Include("Employees") select new { empSched, ..., Employee = empSchedule.Employee.LastName ... }`. Another question is why it has to be `IQueryable`? Use `var` and you will not have to worry...

Comment: Also, why it has to be IQueryable (i.e. what you want to do with it)? It seems to me that you are mixing client and server side in a pretty costly manner (.ToList()) and the stuff that should be joined in the database is brought to the client and joined on the client. If you need to convert IEnumerable to IQueryable you could probably use .AsQueryable() but I think without a deeper understanding of what you are trying to achieve this might not be the best advise.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with the Join-clause. You get this because you demand your query to return a collection of `EmployeeSchedule` but in the select you create an anonymous type. Change your select to return new `EmployeeSchedules`:

```
select new EmployeeSchedule
{
    ScheduleId = empSched.ScheduleId,
    ScheduleDt = empSched.ScheduleDt,
    [...and so on..]
};
```

Comment: if I put EmployeeSchedules, I will not get this, "Employee = emp.LastName + emp.FirstName + emp.MiddleName"

Comment: In this case you should use "var" and not IQueryable<EmployeeSchedule>.